# Raku : is there a SUPER fast way to turn an array into a string without the spaces separating the elements?

Tags: arrays, string, binary, raku

I need to convert thousands of binary byte strings, each about a megabyte long, into ASC strings. This is what I have been doing, and seems too slow:

```
sub fileToCorrectUTF8Str ($fileName) { # binary file
    my $finalString = "";
    my $fileBuf = slurp($fileName, :bin);    
    for @$fileBuf { $finalString = $finalString ~ $_.chr; };    
    return $finalString;
}
```

~@b turns @b into string with all elements separated by space, but this is not what I want. If @b = < a b c d >; the ~@b is "a b c d"; but I just want "abcd", and I want to do this REALLY fast.

So, what is the best way? I can't really use hyper for parallelism because the final string is constructed sequentially. Or can I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** On an old rakudo, `.decode` is about 100X times as fast.

In longer form to match your code:

```
sub fileToCorrectUTF8Str ($fileName) { # binary file
  slurp($fileName, :bin).decode
}
```

## Performance notes

First, here's what I wrote for testing:

```
# Create million and 1 bytes long file:
spurt 'foo', "1234\n6789\n" x 1e5 ~ 'Z', :bin;

# (`say` the last character to check work is done)
say .decode.substr(1e6) with slurp 'foo', :bin;

# fileToCorrectUTF8Str 'foo' );

say now - INIT now;
```

On TIO.run's `2018.12` rakudo, the above `.decode` weighs in at about `.05` seconds per million byte file instead of about `5` seconds for your solution.

You could/should of course test on your system and/or using later versions of rakudo. I would expect the difference to remain in the same order, but for the absolute times to improve markedly as the years roll by.<sup>[1]</sup>

Why is it 100X as fast?

Well, first, `@` on a `Buf` / `Blob` explicitly forces raku to view the erstwhile *single item* (**a** buffer) as a *plural* thing (a *list* of elements aka *multiple item**s***). That means high level iteration which, for a million element buffer, is immediately a *million* high level iterations/operations instead of just *one* high level operation.

Second, using `.decode` not only avoids iteration but only incurs relatively slow *method call* overhead once per file whereas when iterating there are potentially a million `.chr` calls per file. Method calls are (at least semantically) [*late-bound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) which is *in principle* relatively costly compared to, for example, calling a *sub* instead of a *method* (subs are generally *early bound*).

That all said:

- Remember *Caveat Empty*<sup>[1]</sup>. For example, rakudo's standard classes generate method caches, and it's plausible the compiler just in-lines the method anyway, so it's possible there is negligible overhead for the method call aspect.
- See also the doc's [Performance](https://docs.raku.org/language/performance) page, especially [Use existing high performance code](https://docs.raku.org/language/performance#Use_existing_high_performance_code).

## Is the `Buf.Str` error message [LTA](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-LTA)?

**Update** See Liz++'s comment.

If you try to use `.Str` on a `Buf` or `Blob` (or equivalent, such as using the `~` prefix on it) you'll get an exception. Currently the message is:

```
Cannot use a Buf as a string, but you called the Str method on it
```

The [doc for `.Str` on a `Buf`/`Blob`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Buf#(Blob)_method_Str) currently says:

> In order to convert to a Str you need to use `.decode`.

It's arguably LTA that the error message doesn't suggest the same thing.

Then again, before deciding what to do about this, if anything, we need to consider what, and how, folk *could* learn from anything that goes wrong, including signals about it, such as error messages, and also what and how they *do* in fact currently learn, and bias our reactions toward building the *right* culture and infrastructure.

In particular, if folk can easily connect between an error message they see, and online discussion that elaborates on it, that needs to be taken into account and perhaps encouraged and/or made easier.

For example, there's now this SO covering this issue with the error message in it, so a google is likely to get someone here. Leaning on that might well be a more appropriate path forward than changing the error message. Or it might not. The change would be easy...

Please consider commenting below and/or searching existing [rakudo issues](http://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues) to see if improvement of the `Buf.Str` error message is being considered and/or whether you wish to open an issue to propose it be altered. Every rock moved is at least great exercise, and, as our collective effort becomes increasingly wise, improves (our view of) [the mountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enlqVqit62Y#t=37m40s).

## Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup> As the well known Latin saying *Caveat Empty* goes, both absolute and relative performance of any particular raku feature, and more generally any particular code, is always subject to variation due to factors including one's system's capabilities, its load during the time it's running the code, and any optimization done by the compiler. Thus, for example, if your system is "empty", then your code may run faster. Or, as another example, if you wait a year or three for the compiler to get faster, [advances in rakudo's performance continue to look promising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNeu0wK92NE&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: There are a couple ways you can further optimize this. `slurp` is just a wrapper for `IO::Path.slurp` in this case, so calling `.IO.slurp` instead makes this about 2% faster in my benchmarks. If you slurp the file with `:enc<latin1>`, you end up with a buffer of chars like you would with the default UTF-8 encoding, but skip the checks for whether or not the slurped file actually is valid UTF-8 that you're doing when decoding to a UTF-8 string anyway, which makes this about 10% faster as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your help !!! With .decode and other minor code changes, I shave off about 8 seconds for each long string that I have to process. Thanks !!!

Comment: Hi @lisprogtor The metaphor "shave off" means ["to reduce a number by a very small amount"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shave-off). What was your time *before* reducing it to about 8 seconds per long string? Is the reduction enough?

Comment: @lisprogtor Thanks for replying. If you're comfortable sharing more info, I'd appreciate it. I'm wondering what your run-time is per string; I can't tell if the reduction *by* about 8 secs (I had incorrectly written *to*) is a big leap (from, say, 8.1s to 0.1s) or merely a nice speed up (from, say, 20s to 12s).

Comment: Thank you raiph! What I do is download info from the web and analyze the relevant and desired info. The web pages are about 1M. My for loop (mixed in other codes) takes about average 11 sec to anayze a page, and with .decode, the average is reduced to about 3 seconds. Since pages are from Wild Wild Web, I have to use :bin due to malformed utf-8 causing crashes, and hence my other post about pesky utf-8. 8-seconds is a big leap! Thanks!!!